# Logarithms in Summations : Confusion!

Tags: logarithms

I see this simplification and I am confused! I thought there is no explicit way to simplify the logarithm of a summation.

Can someone explain how the the second term( involving the summation), gets converted to a log of a summation of exponential log sums ?

The equation is in the image below! Thanks! :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7q61.png)

Comment: $e^{(\log{a}+\log{b})}=e^{\log{a}}e^{\log{b}}=ab$

Answer (score 1):

This is just an application of the fact that $\log(a)+log(b) = \log(ab)$.

Answer (score 1):

The main trick is as follows:

\begin{align}
 a_ib_i &= \exp\left(\log(a_ib_i)\right) \\
&= \exp \left( \log(a_i) + \log(b_i) \right)
\end{align}

if $a_i, b_i >0$.